# Identity prove by using properties of complex conjugation

Tags: complex-numbers

So what I need to do is verify this identity here:
$(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)=(xa-yb)^2(xb+ya)^2$ for real numbers $x,y,a,b$
I don't know how this can be done through something like $z_1=x+iy,z_2+a+ib$

The second part is show that if $n$ and $m$ are two integers which are sums of two squares(of integers), then so is their product $mn$

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity is not true. Try $x=y=a=b=1$.